# Read py file from one location and point pdf writer to another

Tags: python, pdf, operating-system

I have a longer code which is ran from one location, and this snippet tries to look for information that's in the original folder location, when I'd like to it look somewhere else.

What this does is read from an excel and create PDF files of the row content, one file per column.
Where it looks for the column data it's trying to look in the parent folder, when the data is in the same folder as the excel file.

I can fix the error and have it run if I move the row data "File1/pdf" etc. to the folder the py file is in.
My error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'File1.pdf'

My dataframe:

```
        mod1       mod2       mod3       mod4       mod5
0  File1.pdf  File3.pdf  File1.pdf  File7.pdf  File3.pdf
1  File2.pdf        NaN  File2.pdf        NaN  File3.pdf
2  File3.pdf        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
```

```
    def merge_pdf(models):
        df = pd.read_excel(r'directory of excel', sheet_name='materials')
        df = df.stack().add('.pdf').unstack()
        num = '123456'
        for header in models:
            merger = PdfFileMerger()
            for index, row in df.iterrows():
                if type(row[header]) == str:
                    merger.append(row[header])
            merger.write(f"#{num} ({header}).pdf")
            merger.close()
```

Comment: Sorry, but isn't the problem clear? The file " File1.pdf" does not exist. If it's located in a subdirectory, make sure, you're using the right path.

Comment: That's what I mean, I'm not sure how to, or where to have that function look for the folder I need it to.

Comment: can't you use absolute paths?

Comment: I'm not sure how to get this working like that. My py file is ran from one location but I want to point that specific function to a different path.

Comment: Assuming you know the absolute path you could append it in the df or upon appending to merger, eg: `merger.append('/absolute/path/' + row[header])`